# What is the best solution to manage data from csv file and do some logic and action

Tags: database, validation, automation

## Intro

I have learn basic programming in the past at school (vb) so i understand the logic behind an application and the way it think.

I started this week to learn python because ... I would like to be able to build what i need without having to smash my head in the keyboard.

In the mean time i would like to resolve my problem and i'm asking to all of you in case someone have seen something somewhere.

I have try to search but not sure how to ask so respond was not relevant.

### My Question

I know i can do this in excel but i'm looking for another way if possible.

Does someone knows if there existe an application online or on a mac that give me the ability to:

1- Import data from a csv file and add it in a database. So every day i will log 100 line of data.

2- After that i would like to manage condition related on data store in store in file 2 and 3.

3- That will generated a file 4 where i can see the only important case i have to take care for the day.

I imagine a little bit Access from microsoft but i don't remember if i was able to add parameter on the data i will visualise or condition.

#### What i'm trying to achieve

I have to process a lot of data manually right now and i'm trying to find a way to take out automatically the recurring problem from a list that i receive every day And there is no other way for me than build my own validation process.

**Thank** for your help. I'm new but i will try my best to bring something is this community (Python studies lv1, VB -15ans) . For now i'm building my startup And my expertise is more in technical skill on security products and technical support.

Answer (score 0):

In case i'm not alone that would like to be able to do some basic thing like i was needed without having to program from scratch a database program i found those 2 solution yet:

https://www.zoho.com/creator/

and

http://www.ifreetools.com/